# Clang doesn't compile code but gcc and msvc compiled it

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, clang

I don't understand what's the problem: either in my code or in the compiler (less possible). There is a piece of code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <set>


template<typename T, typename = void>
struct TestA: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct TestA<T, std::void_t<typename T::reverse_iterator>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct TestA<T, std::void_t<typename T::dummy_iterator>> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << TestA<std::set<int>>::value;
}
```

Both GCC and MSVC compile it. I tested it on godbolt with different version of GCC and MSVC 17(local) and 19. Here is a link: https://godbolt.org/z/Enfm6L.

But Clang doesn't compile it and emits an error:

```
redefinition of `'TestA<T, std::void_t<typename T::dummy_iterator> >'`
```

And I'm interested - maybe there is some part of the  standard where this piece of code is incorrect or maybe something else.

Comment: How are _"std::set::reverse_iterator"_ and _"std::set::dummy_iterator"_ defined in clang headers?

Comment: std::set::dummy_iterator is not defined in clang headers at all ( i hope ). You can change dummy_iterator to anythin you want and it won't change the result as the problem is not in the definition as seen below.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, I read the answer and it is interesting indeed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very likely related to [CWG 1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558).

> The treatment of unused arguments in an alias template specialization
>   is not specified by the current wording of 17.6.7 [temp.alias]. For
>   example:
>
> ```
>   #include <iostream>
>
>   template <class T, class...>
>     using first_of = T;
>
>   template <class T>
>     first_of<void, typename T::type> f(int)
>       { std::cout << "1\n"; }
>
>   template <class T>
>     void f(...)
>       { std::cout << "2\n"; }
>
>   struct X { typedef void type; };
>
>   int main() {
>     f<X>(0);
>     f<int>(0);
>   }
> ```
>
> Is the reference to first_of with T being int
>   equivalent to simply void, or is it a substitution failure?

It's a defect that was since addressed, but if the version of Clang you used  doesn't implement the fix yet, it may still consider both specializations as simply defining the second argument as `void`, and not doing the whole substitution failure spiel. The workaround is to not use a plain alias `std::void_t`, but instead a slightly more complex version

```
template <typename...> struct voider { using type = void; };
template <typename... T> using my_void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;
```

For a class template (which is what the alias now stands for), the substitution failure is defined. Plugging that into your example appeases Clang https://godbolt.org/z/VnkwsM.

Comment: Another workaround would be to create traits for each requirement, and then combine them in an `enable_if` with `std::disjunction` (or a requires clause)

Comment: Thank you for help and reference! Sad to hear about this kind of bug in Clang.
Funny, though, I thought that your implementation of void_t is standard. Can't adopt the idea of template aliasing.